# how to save star rating from feedback section in sql database using Golang

Tags: sql-server, go

I am trying to store the star rating from feedback section in webpage to database using golang.

In Home.html I have the html code written for star rating.

```html
<div class="stars">
  <form  action="/feedback" method="POST">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star_5" type="radio" value="5" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star_5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star_4" type="radio" value="4" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star_4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star_3" type="radio" value="3" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star_3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star_2" type="radio" value="2" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star_2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star_1" type="radio" value="1" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star_1"></label>
 <label for="isRate"><span></span></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

And in main.go I have the functions written

```
    var CDSID     string 
    var Rating int
    var CreateDate string
    var rate int

func createUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
    //stmt, err := db.Query("INSERT tbl_fdback SET CDSID='DDUTTA3', CreateDate=getdate(), Rating=?")
    stmt :="INSERT INTO tbl_fdback VALUES($1,$2,$3)"
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("there was an error:", err.Error())
    return
    }
    isRate   := r.FormValue("star")
    if (isRate == "one") {
    rate = 1
    }else if (isRate == "two"){
    rate = 2
    }else if (isRate == "three") {
    rate = 3
    }else if (isRate == "four") {
    rate = 4
    }else if (isRate == "five") {
    rate = 5
    }else {
     fmt.Println("Work harder")
    }
    _, err := db.Exec(stmt,"DDUTTA3",CreateDate,rate)
    if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
    }
    }

func main() {
flag.Parse() 

    dsn := "server=fcdb1198;user id=prxqamydb;password=dbnms#666"
    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", dsn) 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot connect: ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot connect1: ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()
     http.HandleFunc("/feedback", createUser)
    http.HandleFunc(STATIC_URL, StaticHandler)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error starting HTTP server: %v", err)
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is the issue here . Please explain in your post by posting an error you have faced.

Comment: There are no errors but from the webpage when I'm trying to select a star and submit, it is not getting saved in the database

Comment: It's hardly possible to test your code (as it's uncompilable as present) but I'd say there are two points to look at: 1) add debug printouts around the actual call to `db.Exec` to make sure it has really was executed. 2) Use the SQL Server's query tracer tool to see what's happening in the connection made by your server-side.

Comment: just Print the error in log when you are executing the statement to check if an error returns from database.

Comment: I am facing the following error after printing the error  after executing:                                                  2018/06/20 18:51:58 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:57652: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 26 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc042051220)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0xd7
panic(0x7a7140, 0xad9f20)
        
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2795 +0x282

Answer (score 1):

If I get right your star rating values are string eg.: "1", "2"..."5"(not "one", "two"..etc due to `input class="star star-5" id="star_5" type="radio" value="5"`), so you need to convert your `isRate` value:

```
rate, _ := strconv.Atoi(isRate)
```

and get the int value in `rate` to pass in the SQL statement.